# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'JsonRpcProvider') ? what to do next? even my ganache is running in bg

Tags: json-rpc, custom-errors

```js
const ethers = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs-extra");
async function main() {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
    "HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545"
  );
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
    "0x19fe416be106c9cfaeeeb8b01f90a65de6833caf5653727f4bd4ec49aba089ee",
    provider
  );
  const abi = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi", "utf8");
  const binary = fs.readFileSync(
    "./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin",
    "utf8"
  );
  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet);
  console.log("Deploying, please wait...");
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy();
  console.log(contract);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Comment: What version of ethers are you using? I think that it should work with v5, maybe not with v6